# Redshift table size identification based on date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would like to create a query in redshift where I want to pass dates as `between 25-07-2021 and 24-09-2022` and would like to get result in MB(table size) for a particular table between those dates.

Comment: It seems like there is a question behind this question.  What are you trying to do?  Are you slicing a large table into many smaller ones?  Are you finding that these smaller tables are taking up much more space than expected?  (Small tables can take up a disproportionate amount of space.)  It seems like explaining the 'why' of this question may generate more useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "get result in MB" you saying that, if those matching rows were all placed in a new table, you would like to know how many MB that table would occupy.

Data is stored in Amazon Redshift in different ways, based upon the particular compression type for each column, and therefore the storage taken on disk is specific to the actual data being stored.

The only way to know how much disk space would be occupied by these rows would be to **actually create a table with those rows**. It is not possible to accurately predict the storage any other way.

You could, of course, **obtain an approximation** by counting the number of rows matching the dates and then taking that as a proportion of the whole table size. For example, if the table contains 1m rows and the dats matched 50,000 rows then they would represent `50/1000` (5%). However, this would not be a perfectly accurate measure.